# How to link google firebase to ionic's controller.js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm a student and my team have joined an writing app competition. With only such small amount of coding knowledge we couldn't figure out the problem with the following code:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('studentLoginCtrl', function($scope) {

function login(username,password) {

var ref = new Firebase("https://project-2767910204862952587.firebaseio.com");

ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : username,
  password : password
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    window.location = "/SFront";
  }
});


}
})
```

We have already looked up quite a lot of tutorials and a lot of trial and errors. There are no errors shown running the codes, but it isn't doing anything.

The button which is linked to the action is with the following code:

```
<button ng-click="login(username, password)" id="studentLogin-button7" style="font-weight:;" class=" button button-balanced  button-block icon-left ion-android-checkmark-circle ">Log in</button>
```

I already used ng-model to direct the username and password data.

```
<ion-list id="studentLogin-list2" class=" ">
                <label class="item item-input " id="studentLogin-input4">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="username">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input " id="studentLogin-input5">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                </label>
```

Can any experts kindly please tell us that where is the source of the problem and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button's click event is not bind to your function, you should do like below in your controller:

```
$scope.username = '';
$scope.password = '';
$scope.login = function(username,password) {
  //your implemention here
}
```

`$scope` is the bridge of view and model in angular and ionic world.

Comment: @GeoffreyLau: was this the solution? If so, please accept it by clicking the tick mark - it's how we thank people here. If not, please add your own answer, as it might be helpful for a future reader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your routes and maybe the problem is there. You need "link" the view with the controller. Here is an example:

routes.js

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
    .state('signup', {
        url: "/signup",
        templateUrl: "views/signup.html",
        controller: "studentLoginCtrl"
      })
```

Hope it helps.